# One container is different from the others bacause of the word length

Tags: html, css

I want to make all these containers equal, but for some reason - that I believe it is because of the word length of the last container ("CAMISAS") that is shorter compared to the others container - the last container is acting strangely, in a way that I can't put the number in parentheses in the same position as it is in the other containers. So, how can I solve it?

```css
.category-items-box {
    padding: 40px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit,minmax(200px,260px));
    gap: 34px;
}

.category-item {
    display: flex;
    padding: 12px 21px;
    border-radius: 9px;
    border: 1px solid hsl(0, 0%, 85%);
    gap: 10px;
}

.category-img {
    background-color: var(--cultured);
    border: 1px solid hsl(0, 0%, 80%);
    border-radius: 9px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}
  
.category-content {
    display: flex;
}

.title-category {
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-bottom: -14px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: 'Poppins', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    white-space: nowrap; 
}
.quantity-category {
    font-size: 11px;
    color: hsl(0, 0%, 47%);
    transform: translateX(19px);
}
.category-btn {
    color: hsl(353, 100%, 78%);
    font-size: 0.78rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-family: 'Poppins', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    

}
```

```html
<div class="category">
        <div class="category-container">
            <div class="category-items-box">
                <div class="category-item">
                    <div class="category-img">
                        <img class="image" src="https://codewithsadee.github.io/anon-ecommerce-website/assets/images/icons/dress.svg" alt="foto de um vestido">
                    </div>
                    <div class="category-texts">
                        <div class="category-content">
                            <h3 class="title-category">VESTIDO & ROUPA</h3>
                            <p class="quantity-category">(53)</p>
                        </div>
                        <a href="#" class="category-btn">Mostrar Tudo</a>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
                <div class="category-item">
                    <div class="category-img">
                        <img src="https://codewithsadee.github.io/anon-ecommerce-website/assets/images/icons/glasses.svg" alt="foto de um óculus">
                    </div>
                    <div class="category-texts">
                        <div class="category-content">
                            <h3 class="title-category">ÓCULOS & LENTES</h3>
                            <p class="quantity-category">(22)</p>
                        </div>
                        <a href="#" class="category-btn">Mostrar Tudo</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="category-item">
                    <div class="category-img">
                        <img src="https://codewithsadee.github.io/anon-ecommerce-website/assets/images/icons/shorts.svg" alt="foto de uma calça jeans">
                    </div>
                    <div class="category-texts">
                        <div class="category-content">
                            <h3 class="title-category">SHORTS & JEANS</h3>
                            <p class="quantity-category">(64)</p>
                        </div>
                        <a href="#" class="category-btn">Mostrar Tudo</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="category-item">
                    <div class="category-img">
                        <img src="https://codewithsadee.github.io/anon-ecommerce-website/assets/images/icons/tee.svg" alt="camisa">
                    </div>
                    <div class="category-texts">
                        <div class="category-content">
                            <h3 class="title-category">CAMISAS</h3>
                            <p class="quantity-category">(10)</p>
                        </div>
                        <a href="#" class="category-btn">Mostrar Tudo</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi olamundo97! Have you checked the below answer? Let us know please!

Comment: Glad it did. Feel free to accept it please, by clicking on the check button next to it if you think it solved the issue.

Comment: unfortunately, not solved completely. When I change the value of the paddin in the .category-items-box, the number in parenthesis, get out of the container

Comment: This means you need to let the grid to became a little bit wider. Because you are hitting its limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have set a `display:flex` on `.category-item`, `.category-texts` is becoming a flex item taking the minimum width that fits its content. So yeah, the layout you have there is based on the text length.

You could fix this with `.category-texts{ flex-basis:100% }`, so it takes all the available width, and set `justify-content: space-between` on `.category-content`.

I also made some other small changes:

```css
.category-items-box {
  padding: 40px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 300px));
  gap: 34px;
}

.category-item {
  display: flex;
  padding: 12px 21px;
  border-radius: 9px;
  border: 1px solid hsl(0, 0%, 85%);
  gap: 10px;
}

.category-texts{ flex-basis:100% }

.category-img {
  background-color: var(--cultured);
  border: 1px solid hsl(0, 0%, 80%);
  border-radius: 9px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  flex-shrink:0;
}

.category-content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap:19px;
}

.title-category {
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-bottom: -14px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Poppins", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.quantity-category {
  font-size: 11px;
  color: hsl(0, 0%, 47%);

}
.category-btn {
  color: hsl(353, 100%, 78%);
  font-size: 0.78rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: "Poppins", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="category">
  <div class="category-container">
    <div class="category-items-box">
      <div class="category-item">
        <div class="category-img">
          <img class="image" src="https://codewithsadee.github.io/anon-ecommerce-website/assets/images/icons/dress.svg" alt="foto de um vestido">
        </div>
        <div class="category-texts">
          <div class="category-content">
            <h3 class="title-category">VESTIDO & ROUPA</h3>
            <p class="quantity-category">(53)</p>
          </div>
          <a href="#" class="category-btn">Mostrar Tudo</a>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="category-item">
        <div class="category-img">
          <img src="https://codewithsadee.github.io/anon-ecommerce-website/assets/images/icons/glasses.svg" alt="foto de um óculus">
        </div>
        <div class="category-texts">
          <div class="category-content">
            <h3 class="title-category">ÓCULOS & LENTES</h3>
            <p class="quantity-category">(22)</p>
          </div>
          <a href="#" class="category-btn">Mostrar Tudo</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="category-item">
        <div class="category-img">
          <img src="https://codewithsadee.github.io/anon-ecommerce-website/assets/images/icons/shorts.svg" alt="foto de uma calça jeans">
        </div>
        <div class="category-texts">
          <div class="category-content">
            <h3 class="title-category">SHORTS & JEANS</h3>
            <p class="quantity-category">(64)</p>
          </div>
          <a href="#" class="category-btn">Mostrar Tudo</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="category-item">
        <div class="category-img">
          <img src="https://codewithsadee.github.io/anon-ecommerce-website/assets/images/icons/tee.svg" alt="camisa">
        </div>
        <div class="category-texts">
          <div class="category-content">
            <h3 class="title-category">CAMISAS</h3>
            <p class="quantity-category">(10)</p>
          </div>
          <a href="#" class="category-btn">Mostrar Tudo</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
</div>
```